# Looking for a C++ database library that works with Visual Studio 2008/2010

Tags: c++, database

I'm looking for a C++ libraries that can work with Visual Studio 2008/2010, but not MS-SQL. Since MySql is the first database application that I used, it would be much helpful if it also can work with MySql. I had a bad experience with setting up MySqlConnector in Visual Studio. It was such a nightmare, it was so difficult to set up the environment. The reason that I like Visual Studio because of Visual Assist and ViEmu. I feel very unproductive without these two tools. So my priority will follow this order:

**Update**
0. Cross platform, not specific to Windows. ( I only like Visual Studio not MS )
1. Easy to set up with Visual Studio.
2. Has similar design to STL C++. I'm a fan of STL C++.
3. Light weight since I'm still a student, and I only want to experiment.

Thanks,
Chan

Comment: With Visual Studio, the norm is to use ADO. What's wrong with ADO?

Comment: Can ADO also work with MySql? I like Visual Studio as a great IDE, but I don't want get so close to MS products. I want things that are cross-platform. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MySQL is what you are familiar with, then perhaps you should use [MySQL++](http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/).  The FAQ section discusses using it on VC++.

It seems to fit all your requirements except possibly *"Easy to set up with Visual Studio"* since that is entirely subjective, but *download the code* - *compile the code* - *link the code* seems fairly straightforward to me.

Comment: Thanks, I think MySql++ would be my best choice for now. I did some searches, I found many other libraries such as: OTL, OCI, DTL... But they're all limited documentation. It's hard to find a tutorial to set it up with Visual Studio. In fact, I tried MySql++ before, but I failed to install it with Visual Studio 2010. I personally think it's not fairly easy to install any database library for C++ environment. I hope the future release of boost would support a small utility library to support database.

Answer (score 4):

I think [SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) might be a good choice, it's massively supported with ADO.NET.

Read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd4ck1tt.aspx) post, it might give you few aspects on data access from C++.

**Update**
Read [this](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) post to have more on SQLite~C/C++ (no MS).
BTW, many big [companies](http://www.sqlite.org/famous.html) use SQLite.

I am not sure if it stays in the same criteria with MySql.

Comment: thanks, can SQLite work with MySql? Although I like Visual Studio, I'm not a fan of MS. I still prefer cross-platform libraries and conform to C++ STL.

Comment: SQLite, is a database, you can access the data in various ways, if you're looking for the simple low-level way, take a look here: http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html

Comment: @Chan: I also think SQLite is worth looking at. However, I seriously doubt it will work with MySQL.

Comment: thanks again. I still prefer a cross-platform library for C++ not just for Windows ( i.e ADO ).

Comment: @Chan - SQLite is a different database application altogether. If you want to interface with mySQL databases you will need to use MySQL connector

Answer (score 1):

[MySQL's native client has a C API](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c.html) (and therefore easily usable from C++)